# add library to eclipse C++ project (ROOT)

Tags: c++, eclipse, root-framework

I am trying to import library in eclipse but I cant do it. I know there many threads already talked about this issue but I couldn't solve my problem with those. So I appreciate if you can help.
I have text code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <TRandom1.h>
int main(void) {
  TRandom1* myrand = new TRandom1();
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    std::cout << myrand->Gaus(5,1) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and I build and run it like:

```
g++ -c `root-config --cflags` test.cpp
g++ -o randoms `root-config --libs` test.o
./randoms
```

which works fine.
The result if `root-config --cflags` is :

```
-pthread -m64 -I/usr/local/include/root
```

and result of `root-config --libs`

```
-L/usr/local/lib/root -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic
```

Now when in ecplise I change the `C/C++ Build-> C++ compiler -> miscellanoeus` to:

```
-c `root-config --cflags` -fmessage-length=0
```

and add `root-config --libs`to linker miscellanoeus. Now I can build the code . but when I am trying to run it I am  getting:

```
/home/jd/C-workespace/CERN/Debug/CERN: error while loading shared libraries: libCore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable values in the Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: Well you need to make sure the root-config is in the path. and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable has the directory containing the libCore.so

Answer (score 0):

This is a usual compilation error message telling you that it can't find ROOT libraries. Usually, ROOT comes with a setup.sh script in the ${ROOTSYS}/bin/ directory, which you need to source: it does the environment setup for you, and perhaps simply sourcing it will solve your problem.

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but I think there must be a way in it to specify environment variables, e.g. $ROOTSYS.

After 1 minute of googling, I found a promising link:

[Eclipse Environment variable setup](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_run_env.htm)